# CMS based on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

I’m looking for a CMS based on CodeIgniter. Can you suggest what CMS I could use?

I want to learn how to build a CodeIgniter application based using a CMS as a reference.

Answer (score 11):

[PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com/) have a good set of features, and modular design so you can use it as a base to develop a website. The code is in github, so you can download the latest version from it directly with ease, if you have git installed.

The creator of this CMS, [Phil Sturgeon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124378/phil-sturgeon) is also a member here, so you can put your question about this CMS here, and hopefully he can respond it directly.

Comment: Next version of PyroCMS will use Laravel instead of CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 7):

You should all check [Ionize CodeIgniter CMS](http://www.ionizecms.com)

Comment: This is good. One of the best user interfaces I've seen on an open source cms system.

Answer (score 4):

[FuelCMS](http://www.getfuelcms.com/) is the new kid on the block

Answer (score 2):

[ExpressionEngine 2](http://expressionengine.com/) - costs, but is clearly the best.

[PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com/) - free and although looks ugly as sin, the v0.9.8-dev branch is very promising. Does lots more than just blogging.

[DBlog](http://www.davidbehler.de/index.php/category/view/2) - just blogging, but does it well.

Comment: I have checked Expression Engine (EE), but I'm not sure that EE  use CI. because I'm not see model there. and there is no helper library.

am I right ?

Comment: ExpressionEngine 1.x had a similar codebase (CodeIgniter was mostly made up of libraries used by ExpressionEngine and extra bits) but ExpressionEngine 2 has been built on top of CodeIgniter 1.7.x.

It uses some overloading, extending and other trickery to give CodeIgniter extra oomph, but it is a full CodeIgniter application.

What is a helper library? ;-)

Comment: Next version of PyroCMS will use Laravel instead of CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out **[Bonfire](http://cibonfire.com/)**.

It is not a CMS, but a starting point for new projects build with CodeIgniter that require ready-made tools like:

- User Management with Role-Based Access Control
- Fully Modular codebase built around HMVC
- Powerful, parent/child capable theme engine

Answer (score 1):

For free solutions, there are most probably better options available if you look beside just the Codeigniter ones. However, building sites on top of CMS's are in most cases very limiting. (Solely depending on the demanded level of the site of course.)

Take a look at this template library: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Simple-Template-Library/

Together with the active record class that codeigniter offers, you will be up and developing sites in no time at all. Without any boundaries of course!

Comment: Great library! Concise and dynamic

Answer (score 1):

[Codefight CMS](http://codefight.org/) is based on codeigniter as well.

Answer (score 1):

[FuelCMS](http://www.getfuelcms.com/) comes with a decent [UserGuide](http://www.getfuelcms.com/user_guide). have a look at the documentation for module creation. Design is very clean and takes a little time to understand the source. 
I've used PyroCMS as well. Its powerful yet documentation is poor(Phil Sturgeon plz make a better documentation). So FuelCMS is my pick.

Answer (score 0):

MaxSite CMS is based on CodeIgniter. http://max-3000.com/

Answer (score 0):

check ci cms, http://code.google.com/p/ci-cms/

I liked some parts of it, like modular seperation, install/uninstall for modules, themes and pretty url(seo) hyphens for the post urls.

Answer (score 0):

Open Source CMS:

- [No CMS](https://github.com/goFrendiAsgard/No-CMS)
- [CMS Canvas](https://github.com/diyphpdeveloper/cms-canvas)
- [Image CMS](https://github.com/imagecms/ImageCMS)