# Codeigniter CMS

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system

I am making a fund raising website, I want to use Code Igniter as basic core.

I just saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048179/cms-based-on-codeigniter), but its confusing me which CMS will be good.

I need a CMS to be fully flexible to add my own db tables, new components, modules etc?
Which in future I will link to the admin panel.

Can  anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand that was already said in the other thread?

Comment: there were many suggestions, so I am just confused which one will be the best for me\

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMS based on CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048179/cms-based-on-codeigniter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a extensible CMS i suggest to use [PyroCMS](http://www.pyrocms.com)

Comment: @Nick [You could always see for yourself](http://demo.pyrocms.com/). Also, no matter the CMS you choose, you can theme it to look any way you want. As such, basing your choice on looks alone may not be the best choice. As for your requirements, Pyro meets them all.

Comment: i use Pyro for my sites and it works very good, it's fast and, the most important thing, really exensible with modules, plugin and widget!