# Advanced database search for a Codeigniter CMS

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, content-management-system

I'm fairly new to the `Codeigniter` and `MVC` framework, I'm building a content management system (CMS) and I've got the basics done.

I need to be able to search through my companies databases and compile reports based on the results, does anyone know of a good library for this or am I going to have to build one from scratch? I'm using the latest version of `CI` and I'm using the `ion_auth` authentication library for my user login, all this is working great!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread on 
[CMS based on CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048179/cms-based-on-codeigniter)

If this is more advance stuff and you wanted simple crud tutorials (Create update and destroy data) check out : http://avenir.ro/create-cms-using-codeigniter-3/ and for documentation check out  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/